# RPM + rpm installation (not create directory according to SPEC)

Tags: linux, rpm, rpm-spec

I need advice about the following

I build simple spec file and build rpm

I transfer the new rpm to other Linux machine in order to install the new rpm

according to the spec file the new rpm -> test.sh-6.2-2.i386.rpm should create the 
/tmp/MY_RPM_TESTS directory , but this rpm not create the MY_RPM_TESTS and sub directories
please advice why , what I need to fix in the spec file?

RPM installation:

```
   [root@linux1 rpm -Uvh  /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/i386/test.sh-6.2-2.i386.rpm
   Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   This is preinstall script
   Linux linux 2.6.18-164.2.1.el5PAE #1 SMP Mon Sep 21 04:45:05 EDT 2009 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
   1:test.sh                ########################################### [100%]
   Linux linux 2.6.18-164.2.1.el5PAE #1 SMP Mon Sep 21 04:45:05 EDT 2009 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
   Now we wait for sleep
   100

   [root@linux1 ls /tmp

   preinstall_dir
```

my SPEC file:

```
  root@linux /usr/src/redhat/SPECS]# more my_spec.spec
  Summary: An example tool. To show a simple rpm build of the tool.
  Name: test.sh
  Version: 6.2
  Release: 2
  Source0: /root/test.sh 
  Source1: /root/urim.sh
  Group: Development/Debuggers
  BuildRoot:/tmp/MY_RPM_TESTS
  License: OtherLicense
  %description


  %pre -p /bin/ksh
  print "This is preinstall script"
  uname -a
  rm -rf /tmp/preinstall_dir
  mkdir /tmp/preinstall_dir

  %install
  rm -rf %{buildroot}

  mkdir -p %{buildroot}
  mkdir -p %{buildroot}/home
  mkdir -p %{buildroot}/home/home1

  cp %SOURCE0 %{buildroot}/home
  cp %SOURCE0 %{buildroot}/home/home1

  cp %SOURCE1  %{buildroot}/home

  %files
  /home/test.sh
  /home/home1/test.sh
  /home/urim.sh



  %post -p /bin/ksh

  uname -a
  print "Now we wait for sleep" ; sleep  1
  NUM=100
  print $NUM
```

Build the rpm:

```
  [root@linux /usr/src/redhat/SPECS]# rpm -ba   /usr/src/redhat/SPECS/my_spec.spec
  Executing(%install): /bin/sh -e /root/rpmbuild/tmp/rpm-tmp.83360
  + umask 022
  + cd /root/rpmbuild/BUILD
  + rm -rf /tmp/MY_RPM_TESTS
  + mkdir -p /tmp/MY_RPM_TESTS
  + mkdir -p /tmp/MY_RPM_TESTS/home
  + mkdir -p /tmp/MY_RPM_TESTS/home/home1
  + cp /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/test.sh /tmp/MY_RPM_TESTS/home
  + cp /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/test.sh /tmp/MY_RPM_TESTS/home/home1
  + cp /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/urim.sh /tmp/MY_RPM_TESTS/home
  + /usr/lib/rpm/brp-compress
  + /usr/lib/rpm/brp-strip
  + /usr/lib/rpm/brp-strip-static-archive
  + /usr/lib/rpm/brp-strip-comment-note
  Processing files: test.sh-6.2-2
  Requires(interp): /bin/ksh /bin/ksh
  Requires(rpmlib): rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1 rpmlib    (PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
  Requires(pre): /bin/ksh
  Requires(post): /bin/ksh
  Checking for unpackaged file(s): /usr/lib/rpm/check-files /tmp/MY_RPM_TESTS
  Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/SRPMS/test.sh-6.2-2.src.rpm
  Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/i386/test.sh-6.2-2.i386.rpm
```

Comment: The following might help you understand the spec file better: https://github.com/haani-niyaz/sysadmincrumbs/blob/master/rpmbuild/RPMBUILD.md

Answer (score 3):

You misunderstand. `/tmp/MY_RPM_TESTS` is the build root, which *is* created, but is only used temporarily and internally by rpmbuild. It is not meant to be part of the rpm file, and you should never try to install anything in `/tmp` anyway! /`tmp` is for temporary files only.

Comment: so in this case for example I can put the files for example under /var/NEW_DIR ?

Comment: for example BuildRoot:/var/NEW_DIR

Comment: BuildRoot is always temporary and is never part of the generated rpm.

Comment: so what I need in order to save the files after rpm -i ?

Comment: but /home is under /tmp from my example - cp %SOURCE0 %{buildroot}/home

Comment: Yes it looks at the contents of buildroot and puts them under / when it installs. That is how rpmbuild works. You should probably read the documentation!

Comment: so if I summary what you say , I need for example under %install to create new directory as /var/NEW_DIR and then copy the SOURCE to the /var/NEW_DIR ? , about the doc of rpm they not clearly